# io.debezium.DebeziumException: Client requested master to start replication from impossible position

Tags: apache-kafka, mariadb, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using kafka, debezium, and the mysql connector to read from a mariadb

Things were working fine , but when the database device got rebooted i have not been able to get kafka working since

I have this error in `kafka-connect.log`

```
[2023-12-05 16:00:13,482] ERROR [192.168.18.1|task-0] Producer failure (io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler:52)
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Client requested master to start replication from impossible position; the first event 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 57109514, the last event read from 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 4, the last byte read from 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 4. Error code: 1236; SQLSTATE: HY000.
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.wrap(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:1254)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource$ReaderThreadLifecycleListener.onCommunicationFailure(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:1299)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:1079)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:631)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:932)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.network.ServerException: Client requested master to start replication from impossible position; the first event 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 57109514, the last event read from 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 4, the last byte read from 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 4.
```

I understand this as kafka is trying to read from a certian position in a binlog file, but that position is corrupted or something

This is the last bit of output when I try to browse offsets

```
kafkacat -b 192.168.10.6:9092 -t connect-offsets -C

...

{"transaction_id":null,"ts_sec":1701786632,"file":"mariadb-bin.000006","pos":57077411,"row":24,"server_id":18}
{"transaction_id":null,"ts_sec":1701786642,"file":"mariadb-bin.000006","pos":57084545,"row":24,"server_id":18}
{"transaction_id":null,"ts_sec":1701786652,"file":"mariadb-bin.000006","pos":57091679,"row":24,"server_id":18}
{"transaction_id":null,"ts_sec":1701786662,"file":"mariadb-bin.000006","pos":57098813,"row":24,"server_id":18}
{"transaction_id":null,"ts_sec":1701786673,"file":"mariadb-bin.000006","pos":57105947,"row":24,"server_id":18}
{"transaction_id":null,"ts_sec":1701786678,"file":"mariadb-bin.000006","pos":57109514,"row":24,"server_id":18}
% Reached end of topic connect-offsets [17] at offset 6540
```

I think I need to do some stuff on the database side itself to readjust the bin logs?

for context this is the output related to binary logging

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show binary logs;
+--------------------+-----------+
| Log_name           | File_size |
+--------------------+-----------+
| mariadb-bin.000001 |      7634 |
| mariadb-bin.000002 |     73961 |
| mariadb-bin.000003 |    382377 |
| mariadb-bin.000004 | 104859492 |
| mariadb-bin.000005 |  64174670 |
| mariadb-bin.000006 |  57105978 |
| mariadb-bin.000007 |       344 |
| mariadb-bin.000008 |   2224128 |
| mariadb-bin.000009 |   2387968 |
| mariadb-bin.000010 |   4502090 |
| mariadb-bin.000011 |   3657340 |
+--------------------+-----------+
11 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show master status;
+--------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File               | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+--------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mariadb-bin.000011 |  5191150 |              |                  |
+--------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you so much